# How to delete a specific line and replace it in python

Tags: python

I have a python game that writes user data like this: `Bob 3` on to at text file. I'm trying to code so if a player reaches a certain point it will delete the level number (in the example: `1`) and write the new level. I have split the line with this:

```
name, level = line.split()
```

Is there any to do this?

Comment: Better use a database, [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) or something...

Comment: @hcwhsa perhaps using the shelves or pickle will be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"updating" a plain file really mean writing a new file then replace the old one with the new one - you cannot just do an "inplace" update. While technically possible and not really difficult it might not be the most efficient solution for your needs, since you'll have to go thru the whole read + parse old file / write the new one / rename for each update (and possibly have to deal with concurrent access too depending on your application). Using some kind of database (key/value, relational, document, whatever...) would probably be a better solution, since it will take care of most of the housekeeping.

For a very naive answer to your question, it would look like this:

```
def update_level(username, new_level):
   inpath = "/path/to/your/file"
   outpath = "path/to/tmpfile"
   with open(inpath) as infile:
       with open(outpath, "w") as outfile:
           for line in infile:
               line = line.strip()
               name, level = line.split()
               if name == username:
                   line = " ".join((username, new_level))
               outfile.write("%s\n" % line)
   os.rename(outpath, inpath)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Typeerror:Join() takes exactly 1 argument(2 given)

Comment: do i need to create the tmpfile

Comment: hmm. Doesn't work. I have assigned the username variable into the name variable on the name, level = line.split(). Also This definition is above the actual code. Will that affect the behavior of this? Do you need the entire code?

Comment: @Dashadower: "Doesn't work" is about the most useless possible description of a problem. FWIW I tried the above code and it works perfectly... Also, I don't understand what you mean by "I have assigned the username variable into the name variable on the name, level = line.split()", nor by "This definition is above the actual code".

Comment: So I have 2 modules, the game itself, and the levels.py, which contains the levels in def format. So I used the above code on the levels.py, which would import the module game and there is code on the game: name, level = lines.split(). So new_level = level +1.

Comment: @Dashadower : I don't understand a single word of your explanations - and I'm not sure you understand what you're doing neither. The code I posted is a regular Python function and you just have to call it just like any other python function. If you don't understand how to use a Python function then stop writing your game, do the whole official Python tutorial, then come back.

Comment: I do know, I make my own and use oop. So I have created another text file, called players.txt. It records the names of the players that registered. Just the way I used name, level = lines.split(), I used it and put the name varible when I called update_level. So i would call update_level like This:  update_level(name2, level+1)